# What reasons could prevent explicit and implicit styles from applying?

Tags: wpf, debugging, xaml, resources, styles

I have a WPF test project which i use for answering SO questions, somehow this project got quite cluttered over time and some stuff does not work correctly anymore.This may not be a *real* problem since i can just throw it away and create a new one but obviously that is not quite a viable solution in every case so i thought it might be interesting to know what can cause such behavior.

Especially surprising is that even the explicit styles do not apply. e.g. i have this style

```
<Style x:Key="EnlargeImageStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
    <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ScaleX}"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation To="2" Duration="0:0:0.3"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.ScaleX"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation To="1" Duration="0:0:0.3"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.ScaleX"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Which is define in the `Window.Resources` and i apply it to a minimally defined Image like this:

```
<Image Width="80" Height="48" Style="{StaticResource EnlargeImageStyle}">
    <Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage UriSource="pack://application:,,,/Images/Img.png"/>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

And it just won't do anything, if i try to apply it implicitly i also get no results.

So as the title states, **what could prevent explicit and implicit styles from applying?**

(*I do not want to restrict this to my problem, any reason that one could possibly encounter in the wild is fine*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks fine and should work.Make sure that no Other styles or animations are not overriding your default style. While evaluating the value of a dependency property, the wpf dependency property system takes into consideration a few factors like the value set from an animation will have the highest precedence.Go through the below link for more

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx

You can make use of tools like [Snoop](http://blois.us/Snoop/) for debugging in the run time to check which styles are actually applied.

Answer (score 4):

There are two common reasons of why implicit styles are not applied which i want to name:

The targeted element...

- ...is inside a DataTemplate or ControlTemplate (`Application.Resources` are exempt from this)
- ...inherits from the class specified in the `TargetType` as opposed to being the same.

Comment: Excellent, thank you HB.  This explains why MainWindow does not get some property set when a style exists for type Window.

Comment: @Sam: It's a rather unfortunate limitation :(